# Daemon application authentication for OneDrive files

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a OneDrive for Business user account within a large organization. I'd like to have a daemon service running (Python) that automatically uploads files to this user's OneDrive.

This service will be running in a headless VM, so browser-based authentication (especially if it needs to be done more than once) is very difficult.

What are my options for authenticating this app to allow it to write to the user's OneDrive? I've registered an app and created a client secret for it. I was experimenting with the authorization flow described [here](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python), but that SDK is deprecated and no longer supported, so I'd prefer to use Graph if possible.

What are my options for authentication with Python in this scenario, and is any sample code / example available?

Comment: Huh, there's no Python SDK for Microsoft Graph. You may have to call the REST API directly

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft being Microsoft, they appear to have decided to focus almost exclusively on C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both delegated and application permissions are supported on MS Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. Application permissions might not be acceptable for your use case since they would allow access to all users' OneDrives?

Application permissions would definitely be the easiest choice.
But you can also implement this scenario using delegated permissions
You would need the user to initialize the process by authenticating interactively once.
When they do that, store the refresh token in a secret store accessible by the server application.
Then it can use the refresh token to get a new refresh token + access token when needed.
This approach has some more complexity but does allow you to only give access to this one user's OneDrive for the app.

Also, keep in mind that refresh tokens can expire.
The user would need to re-authenticate if that happens.
If this process is critical, application permissions can be a really good idea despite the downsides.

Comment: This is the approach I ended up going with. I found documentation from Microsoft saying that each time the refresh token is used, a new refresh token is generated, so you can keep refreshing indefinitely. So, I set up a scheduled job that refreshes the token every few hours and stores the new refresh token in a secret that my applications can then get it from, and use it while always being certain that it's valid.